# VS Code User Snippets for HTML.ERB Files Only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, visual-studio-code, erb, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I'm trying to include snippets from the Github repository [ERB-VSCode-Snippets](https://github.com/ZneuRay/ERB-VSCode-Snippets) in my Ruby on Rails project.  The json data are found [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ZneuRay/ERB-VSCode-Snippets/master/snippets/snippets.json).  I only want to use them in html.erb files. The documentation for the repository instructs you to do the following:

1. You can just copy the snippets from [snippets.json](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ZneuRay/ERB-VSCode-Snippets/master/snippets/snippets.json)
2. Go to `Preferences > User Snippets` and enter `erb`
3. Paste the snippets code

I've done this, but the snippets are unresponsive in my html.erb files.  After typing them and pressing `tab`, I just get an autocompleted `html` element from Emmet (viz. `<er></er>`).

However, when I paste the [snippets.json](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ZneuRay/ERB-VSCode-Snippets/master/snippets/snippets.json) to `html.json` then they work. For instance typing `er` produces `<% %>`.  The problem is that now these snippets are available in all html files and in all other projects.  **Is there a way to limit the snippets to html.erb files?**

In addition, in an attempt to limit the snippets to the current project, I've created a `*.code-snippets` file under `.vscode` in my project root directory and included the json data there, in hopes that the snippets would be limited to the current project.  They don't work from that directory.  They will only work when inside `code > User > snippets> html.json`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.  The "Select Language Mode" button on the VS Code footer was set to HTML.  When I change the file the erb, the snippets work when under the erb.json file.